# How to connect mysql in django

Tags: python, django

Here is my connection details

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django4webo1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

when i start server error will come and i also need migrations table in db

```
  super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'django4webo1'")
```

Comment: Have you created the database "django4webo1" in MySQL?

Comment: yes i created django4webo1

Comment: i found error thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

You need to create first your mysql database  and then configure your settings as:

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<your_db_name>',
        'USER': '<your_username_in_db>'
        'PASSWORD': '<your_password_to_access_db>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

**Note:** Before you run the mirations and migrate you need to create a mysql database, after that run the migrations `python manage.py makemigrations` and then migrate the database `python manage.py migrate`